# How to check Compute Time usage i.e. (GB-Seconds & GHz-Seconds) by certain firebase google cloud functions per day?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have two different background cloud functions, doing similar things but using different algorithm and libraries for testing.

Now I want to measure the total GB-Seconds & GHz-Seconds by functions to optimize for pricing.

I think this is available in Functions metrics explorer, but I can't create the report.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to attach [labels](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-labels) to your Cloud Functions, then go to your GCP billing report, group by SKU, and filter it by labels to see the breakdown per function.

The only downside is that labels can only be configured in `gcloud` command, GCP Client Libraries, or via REST API, it's currently not yet available in Firebase CLI ([feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/189271172) here).

In this first approach, you'll have to redeploy your functions using `gcloud`. Here's an example and further information can be seen on this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/cloud-firestore#deploying_your_function):

```
gcloud functions deploy FUNCTION_NAME \
  --runtime RUNTIME \
  --trigger-event "providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.write" \
  --trigger-resource "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/databases/(default)/documents/messages/{pushId}" \
  --update-labels KEY=VALUE
```

The second approach to avoid redeployment is to create a [`PATCH`](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/patch) request to add/update labels to your function. It can be done by running this command (update all caps with your input):

```
curl \
--request PATCH \
--header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"  \
--header "content-type: application/json" \
--data "{\"labels\":{\"KEY\":\"VALUE\"}}" \
https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/REGION/functions/FUNCTION-NAME?updateMask=labels
```